# Insurance company sent me huge check instead of pharmacy. Now what?

Tags: united-states, insurance, check

I received a $20,000 check from my insurance company that was supposed to go to my specialty pharmacy. It's made out to me.  Since it was obviously a mistake, I called the pharmacy, and they said to sign it over to them and mail it.

However, since the check is in my name, won't it still be my responsibility if it gets lost on the way to the pharmacy? Further complicating matters is that the pharmacy says the insurance company told them the check was for $24,000, not $20,000.

It seems I have three choices, none of which are exactly great:

1. Sign check over and send via registered mail (though just because it's registered doesn't mean it can't get lost)
2. Deposit check and send a personal check (resulting in tax and IRS reporting issues)
3. Wait until check expires and have insurance company send new check directly to pharmacy (is this even a thing?)

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious. I hate having this hanging over my head.

I (and all parties) are in the USA.

Comment: re: 3. I don't think that could work at all, and will make everyone unhappy. While checks do expire (after 18months where I am), that just prevents them being deposited. It does not discharge the debt, and the expired undepositted check may still be used as part of proof that that the issuer owes the named money. I wouldn't want anyone holding an expired check from me to them for $20K, without a paper trail also indicating that it is definately intended to be voided. In which case, it might as well be actually voided -- the voiding fee is negligible next to that $20K.

Comment: You can't know it's really a mistake unless you ask your insurance company

Comment: I have signed over and mailed smaller checks before (USA), but it was a sign that the billing was out of whack and would take months to correct. The provider came after me for thousands more, and finally I had to write a begging letter basically saying that they should take what Insurance paid, same as all other providers, and I did not have that much money. I hand-carried copies of this letter to the unpaid party, my doctor, and the specialist doctor. It got fixed, eventually.

Comment: Is this pharmacy not a participant in the insurer's network?

Comment: Also- what tax and IRS reporting issues? Insurance claims generally make you whole and are not income.

Comment: I still don't understand why Americans still fool around with checks and are so hesistant to use bank transfers. With them, you don't have this problem.

Comment: @glglgl Some transfer / bill pay methods charge you. A check costs 20 cents, a transfer can cost several dollars. There are other reasons also.

Comment: @nocomprende Thanks, so we have a flaw in the system. In Europe, the costs are the same (and in many cases even 0).

Comment: It seems incredible you would do (1) or (2).  Don't do that.  Phone the insurance company, tell them that as a courtesy you are pointing out they have made some serious mistake.  Tell them they are allowed to come to your house and get the cheque if they want to.  Re the pharmacy, it seems incredible they would suggest that you "sign it over to them", that is amazingly glib.

Comment: Actually, "Registered Mail" DOES mean that it can't get lost.  It can be destroyed, in the event of e.g. an airplane crash, but it CAN'T GET LOST.  Registered Mail carries a paper trail.  At every point, it is either in somebody's hand, and he signed for it from the previous holder, or it is in a LOCKED storage container and the container contents inventory lists it.  Registered Mail is what the DoD uses to move classified documents and equipment, specifically because it is traceable and accountable.

Comment: US Postal Service clerks generally HATE Registered Mail, and will try HARD to talk customers out of using it, because it is a royal pain in the posterior for them.  They can't handle it with their usual disdain, because the penalties for mishandling Registered Mail START with the postal clerk losing his nice cushy job, and go up from there, RAPIDLY.  They CAN include prison time.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Well, it is good to know that some part of the government will do what it promises to do. We need a lot more of that. All jobs should work that way. "Off with their heads!"

Comment: @johnr.strohm Maybe your local post office, but I've never gotten any kind of resistence sending registered mail.

Comment: @Andy, I've run into resistance twice, at two different post offices.  They tried to talk me into using Certified Mail, which is NOT accountable or traceable.  You know your life is getting complicated when you find yourself doing Registered Mail more than once every few years or so.  I've used it for things that HAD to get there, like court documents, or large checks, or nastygrams to collections agencies because a hospital billing department screwed up ROYALLY on the insurance filing and then tried to make me cover their screwup.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Do you have any references about how Registered mail never gets lost because it's impossible? Or about government postal workers being fired for only losing one letter, registered or not?

Comment: It could be a trick. By endorsing you'll be unwittingly accepting that the $4K gap. I was taught with refund checks and the like to write under the endorsement signature "Endorsed Under Protest." But I don't think that's the best option here. There could also be tax implications.

Comment: why did you call the pharmacy instead of whoever sent you the cheque?

Comment: @Xen2050, start by reading the relevant sections of the Domestic Mail Manual.  This is a US Postal Service document.  A good US public library should have a copy.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Public Library? Info on a thinly shaved tree??? This is 2016, *links or it didn't happen* ;-) PS. not everyone's in the usa, and welcome to the future :-)

Comment: @Xen2050, your profile says you're in Canada, so you would have to consult the Canadian equivalent of the DMM.  You'll have to do your own homework to find that.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm It was your comment, and I've never heard of a postal worker being fired for losing a single letter anywhere in America (N or S), and there's definitely no USPS in Canada. From a web search, and [this forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=123223) it sounds impossible for one mistake (and very slow & difficult for many mistakes, if no crimes are involved). If you can't back up your comment I'll assume it's not true. *Cool story though*

Comment: @Xen2050, I think I see what the problem is.  Canada has a service called "Registered Mail", but it appears to be only the equivalent of US Certified Mail, in that it does not provide positive accountability and a verifiable chain of custody.

Comment: If someone gives you money, is that money not then yours? What law do you break by keeping it?

Comment: At least in the UK, people have gone to jail for spending money that suddenly appeared in their bank account. If someone gives you money by mistake, it's not yours.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The insurance company issued the check.  I'd contact the insurance company to have the current check voided and a new one issued to the pharmacy.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  At this amount of money, don't get in the middle of this unless you have no choice.  Contact the insurance company and tell them you are voiding the check and sending it back to them.

Comment: Even if the pharmacy is not in the insurance provider network?

Comment: @user662852 that depends.  Letting an out of network provider handle the accounting of a claim will somewhat depend on your trust in the provider.  Since threadstarter wasn't expecting to receive this payment and was seeking to deliver it to the pharmacy it's unlikely the cost was already incurred by him/her; in this situation there's no point to handling the money.

Comment: @user662852 in any case, when OP contacts the insurance company, they will (hopefully) instruct him on what to do.

Comment: Again, it seems incredible the pharmacy would glibly suggest "oh, just sign that to us".  Totally weird.  They could easily get sued over something like that - the whole thing seems like a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: The receivables people at a specialty pharmacy touch upwards of several hundred thousand dollars each day.  $20k is an extremely common, even small, amount of money for them to deal with.  Additionally, as with all receivables people, their primary concern is receiving payment.  The fastest road to payment is the check that already exists.  This is why the member should contact the insurance company, not the receivables person at the pharmacy.

Comment: The Ins co sent you the check because they figured that the provider (pharmacy, in this case) had already come after you for the money and so they are trying to reimburse you. You need to go talk with the 
Insurer in person to get it straightened out. Conference call, everyone agreeing to the same thing at the same time. Else, it just bounces around and doesn't land anywhere. Telling Insurer to reissue will not help, they already did what they thought was correct.

Comment: @nocomprende We don't know any of that, and I don't see the point of guessing about it.

Comment: @EJP **I** know it because it happened to me in the past and that was the explanation. Why ever else would they pay me anything? They are supposed to be the ones paying people. It was a shock when I realized that the caption "*Amount you may owe or have paid*" on the Benefits Statement means exactly what it says: the Ins Co has no idea whatsoever whether you have paid those amounts or not, or ever will, that part is out of their hands. It is all very sensible, but not something that normal people really get much experience with.

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to accept this answer. By the time it was finally resolved (by taking your advice), months had passed and I'd forgotten I'd even asked. What a process!

Answer (score 25):

Checks are awesome things in that, even if it gets lost the money doesn't change hands until the check is cashed.
I would highly recommend NOT signing a check over and putting it in the mail though. Essentially putting your signature on it is saying yes, pay to whomever. Theoretically acceptable, rarely a good idea.
Call the insurance company and have them cancel current check to reissue to the correct people. Don't forget to write VOID (in huge letters) on the check before throwing away and/or tearing it up.

Comment: Personally, I'd tear it, burn it, and flush the ashes. It sounds like a lot of work but it only takes a few seconds :)

Comment: "Essentially putting your signature on it is saying yes, pay to whomever." I don't know US law here, but in the UK you can "endorse" a cheque payable to you, to make it payable *only* into the account that you name in the endorsement. But IMO the advice to "let the insurance company sort out their own mistake" is better.

Comment: If you Void it, hold on to it. Put it in a safe deposit box. Send the Ins co an image of the voided check with your ID or whatever. But **do not let it out of your hands.**

Comment: It's amusing that your answer begins with "Checks are awesome things" and then proceeds to explain why they're actually a gigantic liability...

Comment: Awesome = Inspires awe. Doesn't mean good!

Answer (score 8):

Option 4: Go **talk with someone in person at an office of the Insurance company.** They have helped me several times with things like this. They can get everyone involved on a conference call and make something happen. But you have to go in. Calling is a good way to waste time and get nowhere, they will throw the issue back and forth.

Find an office and go. This is the most effective solution.

Comment: Is that even possible?  Some medical insurance companies seem to be set up so that it's difficult to even talk to a real person on the phone, much less go talk to them in person!

Comment: @Michael My Ins Co has "retail stores". Not many but a few. They were set up to help people with enrollment and other issues. Strange that there are auto and home insurance offices on every street corner here, but only two retail offices for medical insurance in an entire city. Still, they have been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 7):

So:

1. The amount on the check is wrong
2. The check was made out to the wrong party

What you do:

1. Take a picture of the check; front and back
2. Let the pharmacy know what happened and that you are having the insurance company correct **their** mistake
3. Contact the insurance company and **tell** (don't ask) them that you are sending the check back. Write VOID on it.
4. When sending the check back, make sure to include a letter of explanation

Comment: He doesn't know the amount is wrong.  He knows the person at the pharmacy thinks they're expecting $24,000 not $20,000.  The additional $4,000 may be applicable to a different claim or set of claims.  Further, it's possible threadstarter is receiving the payment because of an error at the pharmacy when the claim was submitted.

Comment: The $4000 could be some sort of deductible, or the result of less than 100% coverage, or some coverage limit being exceeded. Someone at the insurance company may have mixed up, amidst discussion, between the full amount of the claim and the covered amount.

Comment: @quid In either case, I don't think any civilian should be comfortable in being the middle-man of a B2B transaction, nevertheless a giant B2B transaction, especially if everything used to go smoothly in the past. If this is some new policy that the insurance company implemented then that sounds ludicrous and OP should get it in writing.

Comment: @Kaz See my comment above

Comment: I simply commented on your surety that the insurance company was at fault here.  We don't know that the amount is wrong.  And it's possible the pharmacy indicated member reimbursement when it submitted the claim.  I didn't say anything about whether or not anyone should be comfortable with some sum of money.  And further, we don't know that everything used to go smoothly in the past.  You've made a lot of assumptions.

Comment: This solution *could* work, but you will not know how fast and it could be in Limbo for a while, during which time the Pharmacy will start asking you to pay them. Unless you close the loop with an in-person visit, you are just using the "send and pray" strategy. Prayer might move mountains, but not paperwork.

Answer (score 5):

> Deposit check and send a personal check (resulting in tax and IRS reporting issues)

That's a bad idea, unless maybe the check you're receiving is a certified bank draft.

Suppose the insurance company are crooks and the check is fraudulent. It could take weeks or months for some investigation to catch up to that, long after your own personal check was cashed by the pharmacy.

The bank will then put you on hook for the 20 grand by reversing the check, even though the funds had been deposited into your account.

Do not put yourself into the position of a money handler; you don't have the cash base, insurance, government protection and whatever else that a bank has.

And, of course, you're being a **free** money handler if you do that. (You're not even compensated for postage, time and whatnot). If you're handling money between two parties, you should collect a percentage, or else refuse. That percentage has to be in proportion to the risk, since cashing a check for someone carries a risk similar to (and is effectively a form of) making a loan.

Answer (score 4):

In one of your comments you say:

> Even if the pharmacy is not in the insurance provider network?

This is why you got the check instead of your insurance company. I have Blue Cross/Blue Shield, and recently my wife underwent a procedure in the hospital, where one of the physicians involved was not in my providers network.

I got a letter from the physicians office stating that since they are out of network, the standard practice was for BCBS to issue the check to me, rather than to the provider. I received the check and made the payment.

The main contention is the difference in price, and that is what you need to discuss with both the pharmacy (actual billing) and your insurance company (paid benefits).

Comment: Not In Network is a nightmare. I had a situation where one of my providers was NIN in the morning, but magically was In Network in the afternoon of the same day. It was for a substantial amount (thousands) and Insurer gave *me* a check for a pittance, far below the usual rate they would (did, later that day) pay for that service. This was a mess that took about 6 months to straighten out, and afterward the provider *still* wanted to "balance bill" me. I begged off with a letter carried directly to the provider and my doctor and the referred-to doctor. A photo of my recognizable tattoo helped.

Comment: John, did you sign the check over, or deposit it and write a check yourself? Did you take payment in personally, or pay through a portal or by postal mail? Just curious... I trust the mail, but there is something very satisfying about seeing something cleared up and put to rest, in person.

Comment: In my case, it's all local, so I was able to take it over and sign the check over. If you send it via mail, just request it certified/insured with a signature receipt required.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned depositing the check and then sending a personal check. Be sure to account for time, since any deposit over $10,000 the money will be made available in increments, so it may take 10-14 days to get the full amount in your account before you could send a personal check.

I would not recommend this option regardless, but if you do, just a heads up.

Comment: I read somewhere that banks can retroactively void bad checks months after the fact.  If you cash a bad check and then give someone else the money, that bad check could come back and haunt you months from now when the bank catches up with fraud, and you could be responsible for that deposit, with no way to get the money back that you already spent.

Comment: @Kaz Do you have any links/hard info on cheques being marked bad months later? I've read that some "nigerian scam" cheques can take 2 or 3 months to be discovered "bad", but very interested to know if there's a hard deadline after which a bank can no longer "take back your money", US/Can, Europe, anywhere

Answer (score 1):

1. Write **VOID** on the check in sharpie.
2. Cut check down the middle.
3. Return check to sender.
4. Contact all parties telling them about the mistake.

Comment: If you do send it back, DO keep a clear printed copy of the thing before you send it away. Don't discard any relevant paperwork until you are certain that the time for it to completely settle has lapsed - several years. **I would recommend sending them the image and you keeping the original, in a very safe place.** You can make more images if you have the original. Without it, you are out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a mistake. This is done for "Out of Network" providers, and mainly when the patient is an Anthem member, be it Blue Shield or Blue Cross. Even though an "Assignment of Benefits" is completed by the patient, and all fields on the claim from (CMS1500 or UB04) are completed assigning the benefits to the provider, Anthem has placed in their policy that the Assignment of Benefits the patient signs is null and void.

No other carrier that I have come across conducts business in this manner. Is it smart? Absolutely not! They have now consumed their member's time in trying to figure out which provider the check is actually for, the member now is responsible for forwarding the payment, or the patient spends the check thinking Anthem made a mistake on their monthly premium at some point (odds are slim) and is now in debt thousands of dollars because they don't check with Anthem.

It creates a huge mess for providers, not only have we chased Anthem for payment, but now we have to chase the patient and 50% of the time, never see the payment in our office. It creates more phone calls to Anthem, but what do they care, they are paying pennies on the dollar for their representatives in the Philippines to read from a script.

Anthem is the second largest insurance carrier in the US. Their profit was over 800 million dollars within 3 months. The way they see it, we issued payment, so stop calling us. It's amazing how they can accept a CMS1500, but not follow the guidelines associated with it.

Your best bet, and what we suggest to patients, either deposit the check and write your a personal check or endorse and forward. I personally would deposit the check and write a personal check for tracking purposes; however, keep in mind that in the future, you may depend on your bank statements for proof of income (e.g. Social Security) and imagine the work having to explain, and prove, a $20,000 deposit and withdraw within the same month.